# Sharing a script to everyone with link raises an Internal error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to share a script via Library.
I publish a library using "Manage versions", but when I navigate to "File" > "Share", and trying to gain read access to "Anyone who has the link", I got an "Sorry, an internal error has occurred and your request was not completed." while saving.
Any way to fix this?
P.S. I try to do it in 2 accounts.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error in my environment, could you provide a more detailed step-by-step method, with pictures if possible, on how you were able to produce this issue? Also are you getting the same error if you try publishing a different script?

Comment: Yes. Here is a video - it is on the russian, but it is clear what I'am doing https://www.loom.com/share/e909a057d81e4f1a945e872187b7cad5

Comment: Great, thank you! Is the script you're trying to share bound to a Google Drive file such as a Sheet or a Doc? You have to make sure that the permissions are set to be the same on the bound file first (in this case, 'Anyone who has the link') otherwise you get a permission clash and an internal error is thrown.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'll check it.

Comment: There aren't enough details. Are you using a consumer account (usually the domain is gmail.com) or it's a G Suite account? Is the library a standalone project or it's a bounded project? Is the file in My Unit or in Shared Drive (Team Drive) By the other hand, it looks to be something that should be reported to the issue tracker / google apps script community rather than a question for this site.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo It seems, you're right. After I gave read permissions to all users, who has link, error while sharing a script is dissapering. Please share your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Permissions for a  script that is bound to a Drive file must be the same as the permissions of the file to which it is bound. Make sure that the permissions are set on the file first, and then you can get the share link for the script using the same permission settings for sharing.*