# Sharing an app script project results in error

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to share an App script project to an existing email (outside of the Gsuite organisation, but also within) it will result in an error.

`Sorry, an internal error has occurred and your request was not completed.`

The only option is to proceed with `OK`

From the network, I can see this:

```
https://script.google.com/sharing/commonshare?authuser=0
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500
```

```
{
  errorCode: 2,
  responseMessage: {message: "Sorry, an internal error has occurred and your request was not completed."},
  status: 2,
}
```

After reading a [similar question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002530/sharing-a-script-to-everyone-with-link-raises-an-internal-error) answers/comments I've tried to change sharing.
The same thing happens when I try to change the Share permissions to anything else than `Off` (which means only I have access).

Comment: I know you've said you checked out the other thread but just for debugging sake - is the Script Project bound to a file? Also, are you using a @gmail account or are you a G Suite customer with a custom domain? If you are a G Suite customer, are you having these troubles on user accounts, admin accounts, or both?

Comment: G Suite customer with a custom domain and I am an organisation admin

Comment: Okay, is the script bound to a file? Are you having the same issue on all Script files or just a specific one?

Comment: It is my first script so only on this one. The project itself was created from the google slides presentation so I guess it is bind to a file?

Comment: Yes, that means it's bound to a file. Go to the Slides presentation itself and check the share permissions for the Presentation - they need to be exactly same as the Script file and changing one doesn't change the other.

Comment: So I've changed the slides sharing to `Anyone with link` and it still doesn't allow me to change the script sharing from `off`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Slides permissions and the Script permissions? I've not seen the disallowing of changing Script sharing before, I want to see if I can reproduce this is my environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201026/discussion-between-vojtech-and-rafa-guillermo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and thanks to [Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431082/sharing-an-app-script-project-results-in-error/58436005#comment103205934_58431082) I found the way to share it.

It works if I share from the `My projects` dashboard and click `Share script + slides`.

It is still weird that it doesn't allow me to do it separately.